# Error 500 message - but only for certain pages/ operations

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos5, php5, 500-error

I'm a bit confused and bewildered by a problem I seem to be having with Apache/ PHP.

Whenever I try to open certain pages, I'm confronted by an error 500 message. For example, if I try to edit a View in Drupal, after a while the request times out and I get an error 500 message. I've since also found that displaying emails as HTML or accessing attachments in Roundcube webmail also triggers an Error 500.

I've set my PHP memory limit to 256Mb. I've turned on PHP error display and logging, but nothing shows up in the logs.

I checked my Apache error log and this is what I get:

> [Sat Oct 08 00:11:34 2011] [notice] mod_fcgid: call
>   /home/id0074/public_html/index.php with wrapper
>   /home/id0074/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/intl.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php/modules/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Note that the virtual host directory mentioned (id0074) is not for the Drupal site, but another hosted site, however the time matches the access time. There are plenty of similar errors scattered throughout the Apache error log for different times and virtual hosts, however none of my other sites have error 500 messages.

Some other admin pages and all front-end pages work, but the request is handled slowly (ie, the page displays after 5-10 seconds of waiting).

I'm on a VPS running CentOS 5.7 and Webmin/Virtualmin. There's plenty of memory available from what I can see (usage rarely goes about 75%).

Where should I start to look and what might I be able to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load intl.so in either php config or in your script. Install the module, or remove the loading. Check /etc/php.conf /etc/php.d/ and the code for reason.